# Android slide in/out layout with animation

Tags: java, android, animation, slidedown

i have googled a lot about this problem.

I have a LinearLayout with 3 LinearLayouts in it.

The first one is like a header for the second one.
And the last one is just some other content.

I now wan´t to slide up/down the second Layout.
That works fine with this code:

For sliding down:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.show_zeiten); 
                a.setFillAfter(true); 
                zeiten_sonstigeZeiten_Layout.startAnimation(a); 
                zeiten_sonstigeZeiten_Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

My problem is that the 3 Layout immediately jumps done to his new position when the animation starts.
I would like to achieve that the 3. Layout slides down below the second one smoothly.

My animation

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
android:fillEnabled="true"  
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator" >  
<translate       
      android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"    
      android:fromYDelta="-100%"      
         android:toYDelta="0" />
```

Has anyone a hint how i can make this behavior?

Thank you for your help!
Best regards
schwandi

EDIT:

i have tryed to add a animationListener, but none of the methods gets called:

```
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.show_zeiten); 
                a.setFillAfter(true); 

                a.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                        Log.e(TAG,"onAnimationStart");
                                }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                        Log.e(TAG,"onAnimationRepeat");
                                }

                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                        Log.e(TAG,"onAnimationEnd");
                        zeiten_sonstigeZeiten_Layout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                                }
                });


                zeiten_sonstigeZeiten_Layout.startAnimation(a);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are making the changes when the animation starts.
The best method is to add an `AnimationListener` and do the layout changes once the animation ends.

```
yourAnimationObject.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                    }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                    }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            // setLayoutParams here 
                    }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But none of those methods gets called. :/

Comment: It seems that my animation doesn´t start. i call zeiten_sonstigeZeiten_Layout.startAnimation(a); that should be fine, or?

Comment: Yup.. You should start your animation using `startAnimation()`.

Comment: I know this is late, but can you clarify? What exactly do you put in onAnimationEnd?

Comment: @you786: The animation only draws the view in new location, but its actual position have to be changed in the end of animation. That is usually done inside `onAnimationEnd()` using `setLayoutParams()` of the view.